# What is the difference between plugins ion2-calendar and ionic2-calendar

Tags: plugins, ionic4

I found both ion2-calendar and ionic2-calendar plugins in a same project
what is the difference between the two of them.
Also, I wish to know, these plugins are not listed by the command

```
ionic cordova plugin list
```

How to get the list of plugins installed other than cordova?
Below is the portion of package.json of that project.

```
 "ion2-calendar": "^3.0.0-rc.0",
    "ionic-angular": "^3.9.9",
    "ionic2-calendar": "^0.5.7",
```

Answer (score 0):

Found both are different
ion2-calendar is a plugin installed as below:
npm install ion2-calendar moment --save

Documentation :
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ion2-calendar

ionic2 calendar is a plugin installed as below:
npm install ionic2-calendar --save
Documentation:
http://www.codeexpertz.com/blog/mobile/ionic-2-calendar

both are having lot of different workaround

but both plugins are working in a same project without any clash.

This will help who are having some confusion about which one to be used.